# Allow access to stand-alone php file Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme and I want to use `jQuery.load()` to load data from a PHP file in my theme directory called `process.php` to a div in a wordpress page template.

I haven't had any issues with `load()` in the past but Wordpress is preventing me from loading the data or even accessing the `process.php` file in the browser.

When I navigate to the full path of the file (eg: `http://[site]/[theme]/functions/process.php`) I get the following error in Chrome

> Internal Server Error.
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, ****@gmial.com and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I've read similar questions but they involve modifying the `.htaccess` file. Does anyone know how to do this from a theme perspective ie: using `$wp_rewrite`.

EDIT

Linux Server error log states `[Mon Mar 12 14:00:52 2012] [error] [client 121.98.81.237] SoftException in Application.cpp:245: File "/var/www/vhosts/****.co.nz/httpdocs/npr/wp-content/themes/_s_2/functions/process.php" is writeable by group 
[Mon Mar 12 14:00:52 2012] [error] [client 121.98.81.237] Premature end of script headers: process.php`

and this is process.php

```
<?php 
echo "hello from php";
?>
```

Comment: Your web server's error log (if you have access to that) would contain more info about the 500 error. Other than that, it might be something in your PHP code causing the error.

Comment: Not sure if an "internal server error" is generated by Wordpress. Have you checked the log-files? What do they tell you? Also, you might consider asking here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just updated question to show server log

Answer (score -1):

I think the better way is use by `init` action and check the `$_GET/$_POST`, and return the string you want.. and if all ok, you can `die()` the script.

For this way you get access to wordpress db and all..